# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' ASP.net MVC Edit with Image in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, razor

I have a LaptopController with an ActionResult Edit.
I created an edit razor view in asp.net mvc. But when i edit, it return an exception

Here is the code of Controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        LAPTOP laptop = data.LAPTOPs.SingleOrDefault(n => n.ID == id);
        if (laptop == null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return null;
        }



        ViewBag.IDM = new SelectList(data.manufacturers.ToList().OrderBy(n => n.ManufacturerName), "IDM", "ManufacturerName", laptop.IDM);
        return View(laptop);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]

    public ActionResult SuaSP(LAPTOP laptop, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
    {

        ViewBag.IDM = new SelectList(data.manufacturers.ToList().OrderBy(n => n.ManufacturerName), "IDM", "ManufacturerName");



        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);
        fileUpload.SaveAs(path);
        laptop.ImageCover = fileName;
        //UpdateModel(laptop);
        data.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Laptop");
    }
```

The line cause the exception is:

```
 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName);
```

when i debugged it tell me that the fileName was null

this is code for edit:

```
@model GoodLaptop.Models.LAPTOP
```

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Laptop</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageCover, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Chọn ảnh mới
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ Model.ImageCover)" width="120" />(Ảnh hiện tại)
            @ViewBag.Thongbao
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UpdateDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDM, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("IDM")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Please help, Thank you so much

Comment: Where is your `BeginForm` helper? Make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `<input type="file" name="fileupload" />` should be `<input type="file" name="fileUpload" />`, or use `Request.Files[0]` to retrieve the file.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive (`name="fileupload"` will bind fine if the `enctype` attribute is present in the form)

Comment: Even if you do have the `enctype` attribute so that files are posted, you still should be checking for `null` - the user may elect not to choose a file.

Comment: i have had BeginForm, I added new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }, changed to name = "fileUpload". But it doesn't work

Comment: Edit you question to show the `BeginForm()`!

Comment: i have edited. thank you

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` => this should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("SuaSP", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`. Note that if you not specify `FormMethod.Post`, the form may defaulted as `GET` request.

Comment: You are not adding the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute - you are adding a route value - inspect the html you are generating

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, The default is `FormMethod.Post` when using `BeginForm`

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using wrong overload of [`@Html.BeginForm()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd492719(v=vs.118)) helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    // form contents
}
```

This definition matches overload below:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    object routeValues
)
```

Since you're defining `enctype` as `routeValues` parameter, the `enctype` HTML attribute of `<form>` tag is still not set to `multipart/form-data` and `HttpPostedFileBase` still containing null value. You should use this overload instead:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    FormMethod method,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

And your `@Html.BeginForm()` helper becomes this one, because you have controller action marked with `[HttpPost]`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SuaSP", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    // form contents
}
```